# Grab VLC frames through HTTP protocol

Tags: http, frame, jpeg, vlc

Is there any way to access a movie plaing in VLC through HTTP in jpeg/png format.

You see, what I want, is to have a movie playing in my local VLC player, and access currently playing frame through something like http://localhost:9999/current.jpg

Is there sucha way, or maybe someother tool can provide it?

Thanx a lot in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use vlc [mjpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) output module

this cmd line works for me :

```
vlc.exe --sout="#transcode{acodec=none,vcodec=mjpg,vb=512}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=0.0.0.0:8080/image.jpg},dst=display}" movie.avi
```

then, in any webpage (works on Chrome/Firefox)

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/image.jpg" width="320" height="240"/>
```

or directly using vlc http://127.0.0.1:8080/image.jpg

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you a lot, thats a great hint.
its a little bit different from what i wanted originally.
You see, i need to get back single frame, with mimetype of jpeg, not motion jpeg. As result i would like to se a single jpeg image returned by vlc, and manually to have to press refresh to get the current frame.
Again, thenk you a lot for your help

Comment: maybe tweaking these settings could work. you could also produce some snapshots at specified interval. see http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

In the case of experiencing delay in the mjpg stream you can cancel the live view as follows:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=MJPG,vb=512}:std{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=0.0.0.0:8080/image.jpg,delay=0}
```